# Parsing a XML string with no sense of keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm using OpenUri and RSS in Rails 5.2.3 and Ruby 2.6.1 to do this.

I'm trying to parse [WeWorkRemotely's](https://weworkremotely.com/categories/remote-product-jobs.rss) RSS feed, however, they have one field description that contains all the information in a string. For example, when I parse it in Rails it returns:

```
"<img src=\"https://we-work-remotely.imgix.net/logos/0015/9022/logo.gif?ixlib=rails-2.1.3&w=50&h=50&dpr=2&fit=fill&auto=compress\" alt=\"Logo.gif?ixlib=rails 2.1\" />\n\n<p>\n  <strong>Headquarters:</strong> San Francisco \n    <br /><strong>URL:</strong> <a href=\"http://www.loom.com\">http://www.loom.com</a>\n</p>\n\n<h1><strong>About Loom</strong></h1><div>Loom is a new kind of work communication tool, already helping over a million people get their message across through instantly shareable videos. Our users work at companies like HubSpot, Square, Uber, GrubHub and LinkedIn. Our mission is to be the global leader in human workplace communication. Founded in 2016, Loom has raised $15 million from top-tier investors including Kleiner Perkins, General Catalyst and Slack Fund.</div><h1><strong>The Role</strong></h1><div>As a Technical Support Engineer, you will be a key part of Loom's support experience at scale and provide timely and effective resolution to customer issues by applying your technical and troubleshooting skills.</div><div><br></div><div>We are looking for support champions who are genuinely happy to help others. If this sounds like you, you came to the right place!<br><br><strong>As a Technical Support Engineer, you  will…</strong>\n</div><ul>\n<li>Help customers through email to ensure they are successful with our product</li>\n<li>Leverage effective troubleshooting to quickly identify the source of customer issues and provide a prompt and appropriate solution</li>\n<li>Troubleshoot, investigate, and create detailed bug reports for our Engineering team</li>\n<li>Jump on ad-hoc calls with customers to troubleshoot issues live, as necessary</li>\n<li>Identify bugs, test, report, and working with our Engineering team to assist with a fix</li>\n<li>Actively collect insights from customers and focus on closing the communication loop by providing product feedback to the team</li>\n<li>Provide timely updates to the Support and Engineering Managers regarding new trends in issues</li>\n<li>Develop and document best practices to enhance SL2 troubleshooting processes</li>\n<li>Create technical documentation such as FAQs, guides, knowledge-base articles and how-to’s for Loom customers</li>\n<li>Help the Engineering team develop tools to help our Support team work quickly and efficiently</li>\n<li>Dive into the codebase and gaining domain knowledge of different parts of Loom</li>\n<li>Make efficient changes to the codebase to solve small and quick tasks/issues</li>\n</ul><div>\n<br><strong>You could be a good fit if you have..</strong>\n</div><ul>\n<li>Previous experience delivering excellent support experiences with respect, empathy and understanding</li>\n<li>A minimum of 4+ years of Technical Support and Customer Support experience</li>\n<li>Gained experience/proficiency in Saas solutions and electron apps (CSS, JavaScript, HTML) or have earned a degree in a technical field like computer science</li>\n<li>Technical understanding and ability to troubleshoot and resolve technical problems on your own</li>\n<li>The ability to handle high volume of support conversations</li>\n<li>Excellent written and spoken English</li>\n<li>Are available to work in the Central or Pacific Time Zone and on a full-time schedule that may span weekends and may include holidays as our customers need us</li>\n</ul><div>\n<br><strong>A bonus if you have experience with...</strong>\n</div><ul>\n<li>Installation, configuration, and troubleshooting of Windows and Mac</li>\n<li>Troubleshooting protocols like HTTP, HTTPS, WebSockets, DNS</li>\n<li>Understanding of TCP/IP and ARP to run packet traces and troubleshoot network issues</li>\n<li>Any of these certifications: Cisco CCNA, Microsoft Certified Solutions Expert (MCSE), Apple Certified System Administrator, CompTIAA+, CompTIA Network+</li>\n</ul><div><br></div><div><strong>Perks at Loom</strong></div><div><br></div><div>* Competitive compensation and equity package</div><div>* Medical, dental, and vision coverage (US-based team), healthcare reimbursement (non-US based team)</div><div>* Unlimited PTO</div><div>* Remote-first team</div><div>* Paid parental leave</div><div>* Yearly off-site retreats (this year we went to Costa Rica for a week!)</div><div>* Learning &amp; Development reimbursement</div><div>* Wellness reimbursement</div><div> </div><div><strong>SF office perks</strong></div><div>* Remote weeks every other month</div><div>* Daily in-office lunch, unlimited snacks &amp; drinks</div><div><br></div><div><strong>Remote-specific perks</strong></div><div>* Home office &amp; technology stipends</div><div>* New Hire Onboarding in SF</div><div><br></div><div><strong>Loom is an equal opportunity employer.</strong></div><div>We are actively seeking to create a diverse work environment because teams are stronger with different perspectives and experiences.</div><div><br></div><div>We value a diverse workplace and encourage women, people of color, LGBTQIA individuals, people with disabilities, members of ethnic minorities, foreign-born residents, older members of society, and others from minority groups and diverse backgrounds to apply. We do not discriminate on the basis of race, gender, religion, color, national origin, sexual orientation, age, marital status, veteran status, or disability status. All employees and contractors of Loom are responsible for maintaining a work culture free from discrimination and harassment by treating others with kindness and respect.</div>\n\n<p><strong>To apply:</strong> <a href=\"https://jobs.lever.co/useloom/15398ec6-b2c1-4f95-9ef5-8fa2a62c1bed?lever-origin=applied&amp;lever-source%5B%5D=WeWorkRemotely\">https://jobs.lever.co/useloom/15398ec6-b2c1-4f95-9ef5-8fa2a62c1bed?lever-origin=applied&amp;lever-source%5B%5D=WeWorkRemotely</a></p>\n"
```

What would be the best way for me to actually grab data from this block? Even if I try to pick things up like `img src`, `head quarters`, or `a href` links, it's a big string where I can't easily split that makes sense.

Comment: not sure why it's being down voted (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't treat it as a string, treat it as an HTML document. Then you can employ the full power of CSS or XPath selectors (or even manual traversal using Ruby methods).

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(str)

# img src
doc.at_css('img')["src"]
# => "https://we-work-remotely.imgix.net/logos/0015/9022/logo.gif?ixlib=rails-2.1.3&w=50&h=50&dpr=2&fit=fill&auto=compress"

# headquarters
doc.at_xpath('.//strong[contains(text(), "Headquarters")]/following-sibling::text()').text.strip
# => "San Francisco"
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize Nokogiri was able to do that. I tried using it, but with similar effect as open-uri. Thank you! I marked your answer as correct!

Comment: how would you deal with the message body stuff that's in Divs
`<div>Loom in workplace communication. Founded in 2016, Loom has raised $15 million from top-tier investors including Kleiner Perkins, General Catalyst and Slack Fund.</div>` and `<strong>As a Technical Support Engineer, you  will…</strong>\n</div><ul>\n<li>Help customers through email to ensure they are successful with our product</li>`

Comment: Define "deal with". If you have a pattern you can identify, get the text content using Nokogiri, then apply regexp. If you don't have a string pattern but do have a syntactic pattern, NLTK to parse the sentence, then extract the relevant parts of speech. If you can't identify any pattern but you have a large corpus of similar texts, you could use deep learning. If you have none of those, hire a human.

Comment: Not having any pattern is actually the problem. Seems like an API issue.